# Chrome userscript to autoclick popup button

Tags: google-chrome, popup, click, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am an expert for a web site whose page pops up an "Accept" button when a client poses a question. I'd like a userscript (Chrome) that will automatically click it as soon as it pops up, without needing a hotkey. Instant and automatic. Suggestions?

Comment: What did you tried? What didn't work? StackOverflow is centered question on precise problem. The Q&A format also don't handle suggestions-type question, so they rarely are well accepted. I welcome you to SO and invite you to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I've tried Jitbit, McUrbee, but doesn't work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happened when you tried them? Can you show the code? The error?

Comment: What happens is that since I don't know code, I'm trying to record a macro, but they involve hotkeys to click on specific coordinates. The button appears as a green button that says "Accept." I'm sure other experts for the site are using bots or userscript so that their button is autoclicked as soon as it pops up. It's so fast by them that the button isn't even showing now on mine. Can you help? Does this require a userscript.

Comment: You need to post enough info for us to duplicate the problem. Post an MCVE.